# Sorting horizontal and vertical query from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting

I realy need help to make this work coz i dont know how sorting works and i am begginer in this field guys.

I have table like this:
jobs - hours - user

I am trying to sort and output table like this:
Find all jobs that exist in table horizontal
and then, in vertical menu show all users with hours (if exist) on all jobs add 0 if not

```
       joob 1 - joob2 - joob 3 - joob 4
mark     0        3       1        0 
benny    7        5       0        0
john     0        0       0        3
```

How do i query and sort like this output as html ?
I know latter to group and calculate but this i am having problem with.

Comment: can you show table structure ?

Comment: Table name: jobs_users:  Columns: jobs - hours - users

Comment: joob 4 doesn't exist in the database

Comment: Why joob 4 doesn't exist? It can exist as so joob 5, joob 6 and so on. 
If user didnt worked on that joob then it would be 0.
Oh i see, lets say John was working on Joob 4.

Comment: So, if no one works on a joob, then the joob doesn't exist?

Comment: In which case, the only query you need is `SELECT job, hours, user FROM my_table ORDER BY job, user;`. Everything else can be handled in PHP, with a simple loop.

Comment: Yes, if no one works on a joob, joob doesn't exist.
Query is fine, could you please write and explain then?